# Correlation and array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Kindly somebody help me in this.

I have two arrays of equal size 8x8.

And I need covariance of Column 1 of array 1 with the column 1  of second one.
After that I want to find Column 1 with the column 2 of second array.
After that I want to find Column 1 with the column 3 of second array.
After that I want to find Column 1 with the column 4 of second array.

After that I want to find Column 2 with the column 1 of second array.
And so on

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want a measure as to how a column of first array varies with a column of second array. If yes, then that will be a scalar, otherwise, if you calculate the covariance matrix of two vectors, it is going to be a... matrix, obviously.

The following solution is based on the fact that covariance of two vectors is their correlation times the product of their standard deviations. More succinctly, for two random variables X and Y,

```
cov(X,Y)=corr(X,Y)*(sd(X)*sd*Y))
```

Thus, the solution to your question is:

```
pairCovariance=corr(X,Y).*(std(X).'*std(Y))
```